# The series $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}n^{-z}$ converges locally normally

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Show that the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}n^{-z}$ converges locally normally on the half plane $\{z:\text{Re}(z)>1\}$

$\displaystyle n^{-z}=\frac{1}{n^z}\le\frac{1}{|n^z|}=\frac{1}{n^{\text{Re}(z)}}\le\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ (If $z=x+iy$ with $x>1$ then $\exists\epsilon>0$ s.t. $x>1+\epsilon$)

So it converges absolutely and also normally, because then there is always an $r$-neighbourhood for every $z_0\in\{z:\text{Re}(z)>1\}$, such that;

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n\ge1}||n^{-z}||_{\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}}=\sum\limits_{n\ge1}\sup\limits_{z\in\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}}|n^{-z}|=\sum\limits_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^{\inf\{\text{Re}(z):z\in\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}\}}}$

but how can I show formally that $\exists\delta>0:$ $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^{\inf\{\text{Re}(z):z\in\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}\}}}\le\frac{1}{n^{1+\delta}}$

Is it enough to say $\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}\subsetneq\{z:\text{Re}(z)>1\}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

To justify $|n^{-z}|\le n^{-1-\delta}$, 
you need an inclusion of the form
$$\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}\subset\{z:\text{Re}(z)\ge 1+\delta\}$$
To this effect, it seems reasonable to choose $r=\frac12(\operatorname{Re} z_0-1)$, because it leaves you room for $\delta$.